# display ASCII data in ColdFusion from a <cfset> parameter

Tags: coldfusion, ascii, chr

I have set up a language file rather than in the database, so I have for example in the language file…

```
<cfset lang_back_to_results = "< retour aux résultats">
```

So I have in my cfm page…

```
<cfoutput>#lang_back_to_results#</cfoutput>
```

This works fine but it does not correctly display the accent, so I tried to use ASCII and CHR inputs in the language file but with no success…

```
chr(233) &eacute;
```

Any ideas on how to display the text correctly?

Comment: If it doesn't display the accent, what _does_ it display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have this in the top of your 'language file', and whatever .cfm file you're including it in:

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8" />
```

See:

- https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfprocessingdirective

Comment: Excellent - that little bit of code did the trick. Man thanks

Answer (score 1):

do you have your `content-type` set?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: Hi, yep, its set to `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: can you post a reproduceable test case? if I copy and paste your two lines into a page it works fine even if I don't see the `content-type`